# How to check if a workbook is open

Tags: c#, exception

I have a small utility that I use for cleaning up Excel workbooks. When I try to open a file for cleaning that is already open in Excel it throws

> 'System.IO.IOException'.

Is there some way I can place a check in the code so that it checks to see if the workbook is open and if so, throws an error box so the user can close out of it and close Excel before proceeding?

```
public bool CleanFile(string docPath)
{
    // Open the document for editing.
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docPath, true))
```

[image]

Comment: catching the exception is the only reasonable course of action.  You might check if it's open, decide it's not, then before your next block of code runs the user happens to open it - your exception is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method before you open the document, and if it returns true, alert the user.

```
    public static bool IsFileOpen(string path)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("being used by another process"))
                return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When I try to run it I receive the following: The type or namespace name 'FileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you need to add a reference to System.IO

Comment: Note that [as per my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725246/how-to-check-if-a-workbook-is-open#comment53293343_32725246), by the time this function returns, the file may have been locked by another process anyway - you may as well just try to access the file without checking, because you're going to need another exception handler around that block anyway...

Comment: It is not a good idea to try to do anything based on the error message text as these are localized.

Comment: Thanks guys - I have "System.IO.Log" but no "System.IO" available?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Good point. What would you suggest then? Just catching the generic IOException, or using something like an HResult that's more specific?

Comment: @greenMamBa I'm not sure why you don't have System.IO available. Did you add this to the top of the file where the IsFileOpen method is located? using System.IO;

Comment: Ok, I got System.IO in there, but I'm still getting the exception

Comment: I have the method in the code now with no errors, however, I don't know how to implement it in-line with the "CleanFile" process. Perhaps this is too much of a beginner question for here

Comment: @greenMamBa Yeah it depends on what kind of application you're creating and how you want to report errors back to the user. I just exited out of my action (report creation) and brought up a label instructing the user to close the document and try the action again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wooters - I was able to get it integrated with some help from a colleague - works like a charm!